# NPM package not visible on site

Tags: javascript, npm, npmjs

Today i have added 2 new packages to a newly created organisation on npmjs.com.
These packages can be downloaded through the command line so no issues there.

My problem lies in the fact that they do not show up on npmjs.com itself.
I'd expect it to be a cache related thing, but it has taken quite some time now without them showing up.

After publishing the # of packages does increment as seen below.

Any idea how i can get the package detail page (and readme) to show so i can share the package with my team? Many thanks!

[image: img1]

Comment: How are you trying to install your packages?  When I run [`npm i @michaelkoelewijn91/scrollanimate`](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=maintainer:michaelkoelewijn91), I get an error.

Comment: I experienced the same this morning. I figure out it should be a bug in their caching strategy that does not invalidate cache of users package statistics or something similar because I could reach the package page though the url where it is supposed to be.

In my case, here it is the package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/smart-spinner and here my profile: https://www.npmjs.com/~joanmi. It tells that I have 13 packages (right) but I can see only 12.
Probably we should wait until tomorrow to confirm it. But, as I said, it seems caching issue...

Comment: @zero298 try npm i @michaelkoelewijn/scrollanimate

Comment: @bitifet oh snap, i can confirm that going directly to the url works. Let's wait it out and see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: Weird, yeah, that works.  The site was just recently overhauled so maybe there is a backend issue.  You may want to open a bug on the [GitHub issues page](https://github.com/npm/www/issues).

Comment: Good point, @zero298. Done: https://github.com/npm/www/issues/380

Comment: As a temporary workaround, I just noticed that our package list can be approached though search engine. Ex.: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=maintainer:joanmi . In fact this is better than profile page which shows deprecated packages indistinguishably.